# "Error: [$injector:unpr]" Angular JS error

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I'm new to angular JS and I'm trying to generate an html report page using the code below but I keep getting the following error(and a blank page):

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=fangFilterProvider%20%3C-%20fangFilter
    at angular.js:38:1
    at angular.js:4789:19
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4944:32)
    at angular.js:4794:28
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4944:32)
    at angular.js:20571:14
    at U (angular.js:15214:50)
    at angular.js:15168:7
    at q (angular.js:403:11)
    at U (angular.js:15167:5)
```

I've checked the link in the error and everything seems to look fine with my code(no typo or injection in a service). I tried to debug the code with the Chrome Batarang extension without any success. However, it looks like it fails at the "$scope.content =" line. Not sure why. Is there something wrong with how I'm populating the $scope variable?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme_thehive.css" />
</head>

<body  ng-app="report" ng-controller="tableController" >
    
    <div class="report-SecurityTrails" ng-if="success"> 
        
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            SecurityTrails Whois report ({{content.domain}})
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div ng-if="content.contacts.length === 0">
              No records found
            </div>
            <div ng-if="content.contacts.length !== 0">
              <dl class=" dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Domain: </dt>
                <dd class="wrap">{{content.domain|| "-"}}</dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Contact email: </dt>
                <dd class="wrap">{{content.contactEmail || "-"}}</dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Nameservers: </dt>
                <dd class="wrap" ng-repeat="ns in content.nameServers">{{ns}}</dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Created date: </dt>
                <dd class="wrap">{{content.createdDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Updated date: </dt>
                <dd class="wrap">{{content.updatedDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Expires date: </dt>
                <dd class="wrap">{{content.expiresDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Registrar name: </dt>
                <dd class="wrap">{{content.registrarName}}</dd>
              </dl>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-info" ng-if="success"> 
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Contacts info</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div ng-if="content.contacts.length === 0">
              No records found
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="contact in content.contacts">
              <dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-repeat="(key, value) in contact">
                <dt>{{key}}</dt>
                <dd>{{value}}</dd>
              </dl>
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div> 
      
      <!-- General error  -->
      <div class="panel panel-danger" ng-if="!success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           <strong>{{artifact.data | fang}}</strong>  
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-if="content.errorMessage">
            <dt>
              <i class="fa fa-warning"></i></dt>
            <dd class="wrap">{{content.errorMessage}}</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('report', []);
    app.controller('tableController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.success = true
    $scope.content =        
         {
                "updatedDate": null,
                "status": null,
                "registrarName": "Name: One.com A/S\nRegistrar Registrar Website: http://www.test.com",
                "private_registration": true,
                "nameServers": [
                    "ns02.one.com",
                    "ns01.one.com"
                ],
                "expiresDate": null,
                "endpoint": "/v1/domain/test.com/whois",
                "domain": "test.com",
                "createdDate": null,
                "contacts": [
                    {
                        "type": "technicalContact",
                        "organization_count": 207907,
                        "organization": "test.com A/S",
                        "email_count": 491587,
                        "email": "test@test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "registrant",
                        "name_count": 47404,
                        "name": "NOT DISCLOSED!"
                    }
                ],
                "contactEmail": null
        }
             
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: Looks like removing the line below make the error dissapear(but I'm **still getting a blank page**). However, I also need that part in the form. I think I might have to add the Artifact element as model into the scope:

**{{artifact.data | fang}}**

UPDATE2: I was able to display the table after commenting out the ng-if="succss" line. I guess I will have to troubleshoot that later on as it should be working . However, no data from the json is being displayed. Only the Hmtl portion.

UPDATE3: I was able to resolve the issue. I modified the json value. I think the hierarchy in the json structure was not at the right level. I removed the parents element so I'm at the right level. I also added the $scope.success line. I can just extract the value from the originating json and populate the $scope.success model.I could also modify the form to ng-if content.success, but I dont want to do that. I've updated the code above to reflect my changes.

Comment: Does any error appear in the console after removing mentioned line?
If you use {{artifact.data}}, the 'artifact' variable should exist in the scope. Now you have only 'content' variable in the scope.

Comment: The error goes away when I remove the line. However, it looks like the scope data does not populate  the form. I guess its also why the ng-if = "success" always return false.

Comment: There is no error in the console either.

Comment: Problem resolved, see UPDATE3